# Setting the JDK for Eclipse in MAC

Tags: java, eclipse, macos

I bought a MacBookPro and I'am newbie with this OS.I downloaded the JDK from Oracle's website and installed it (/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk_1.7...) so everything is fine when I enter "java -version" in Terminal it says : 1.7. But I could not set the 1.7 JRE on Eclipse.When I try to Add the JDK at "Java/InstalledJREs/Add" in Eclipse it doesn't accept the Home directory of jdk_1.7/Contents/Home.. What am I doing wrong, couldn't find the way to solve.

Also After installation of 1.7, eclipse cant compile a simple HelloWorld.java file.It gives error something like; "java.lang.UnixProcess" If I remove the 1.7 it works and "java -version" says 1.6

Comment: You specify the full JRE path for the installed JREs - something like `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_51.jdk/Contents/Home`

Comment: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_60.jdk/Contents/Home which I am trying but Eclipse says "The Home directory does not exist" I tried several eclipse versions and ADT still same..

Answer (score 6):

You need to add the JDK on the eclipse.ini file first. Just go to the eclipse folder and find the eclipse.ini.
In the eclipse.ini file there will be a section called
-vm
Add your path to the JDK there.
[image]

Now if you are not aware of the path of your jdk, you can use the below command:
/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.8

Once you have your path. Just paste it in the eclipse.ini. Your eclipse should work now.

Answer (score 1):

After you install Eclipse, it generally maps to a JRE and because a JRE doesn't have the javac compile program, you won't be able to compile code until you first add a JDK runtime environment and then map your project to have that JDK included as a library.     One think I also do sometimes is edit the **eclipse.ini**  and add a **-vm**  argument that points to **{JDK_HOME}/bin/javaw**  .

Comment: Wrong, Eclipse has its own compiler. It works perfectly well on a runtime only.

Comment: Your right, my answer is geared toward either a Linux or Windows perspective.  I assumed Eclipse would have similar functionality on a Mac.

Answer (score 1):

Note, the -vm MUST be specified BEFORE the -vmargs in the eclipse.ini, like this:

```
-vm 
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_191.jdk/Contents/Home/bin
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.7
-XstartOnFirstThread
-Dorg.eclipse.swt.internal.carbon.smallFonts
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m
-Xms40m
-Xmx512m
-Xdock:icon=../Resources/Eclipse.icns
-XstartOnFirstThread
-Dorg.eclipse.swt.internal.carbon.smallFonts
```

To check the VM version:
Eclipse -> About -> Installation Details (switch to Configuration tab) shows:

```
....
-showlocation
-vm 
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_191.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/../jre/lib/server/libjvm.dylib
```