# Eclipse Scala is crashing on startup on Mac OS

Tags: java, eclipse, scala

I am following a course in Coursera https://www.coursera.org/specializations/scala that uses Eclipse for scala 
http://scala-ide.org/ 
When I try to launch it I get this error 
[image]

```
!SESSION 2019-09-19 13:35:58.107 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=4.7.0-vfinal-2017-09-29T14:34:02Z-Typesafe
java.version=12.0.2
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=macosx, ARCH=x86_64, WS=cocoa, NL=en_BG
Framework arguments:  -keyring /Users/aghan/.eclipse_keyring
Command-line arguments:  -os macosx -ws cocoa -arch x86_64 -keyring /Users/aghan/.eclipse_keyring

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2019-09-19 13:36:04.968
!MESSAGE Application error
!STACK 1
org.eclipse.e4.core.di.InjectionException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/annotation/PostConstruct
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.internalMake(InjectorImpl.java:410)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.make(InjectorImpl.java:318)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts.ContextInjectionFactory.make(ContextInjectionFactory.java:162)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.E4Application.createDefaultHeadlessContext(E4Application.java:491)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.E4Application.createDefaultContext(E4Application.java:505)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.E4Application.createE4Workbench(E4Application.java:204)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.lambda$3(Workbench.java:614)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:336)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:594)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:148)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:151)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:388)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:243)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:653)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:590)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1499)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/annotation/PostConstruct
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.inject(InjectorImpl.java:124)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.internalMake(InjectorImpl.java:399)
    ... 22 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.annotation.PostConstruct cannot be found by org.eclipse.e4.core.di_1.6.100.v20170421-1418
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:433)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:395)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:387)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:150)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    ... 24 more

!ENTRY org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench 4 0 2019-09-19 13:36:04.974
!MESSAGE FrameworkEvent ERROR
!STACK 0
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/annotation/PreDestroy
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.disposed(InjectorImpl.java:450)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.Requestor.disposed(Requestor.java:156)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.ContextObjectSupplier$ContextInjectionListener.update(ContextObjectSupplier.java:78)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.TrackableComputationExt.update(TrackableComputationExt.java:111)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.TrackableComputationExt.handleInvalid(TrackableComputationExt.java:74)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.EclipseContext.dispose(EclipseContext.java:178)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.osgi.EclipseContextOSGi.dispose(EclipseContextOSGi.java:99)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.osgi.EclipseContextOSGi.bundleChanged(EclipseContextOSGi.java:141)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.dispatchEvent(BundleContextImpl.java:908)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.ListenerQueue.dispatchEventSynchronous(ListenerQueue.java:148)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxEventPublisher.publishBundleEventPrivileged(EquinoxEventPublisher.java:213)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxEventPublisher.publishBundleEvent(EquinoxEventPublisher.java:120)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxEventPublisher.publishBundleEvent(EquinoxEventPublisher.java:112)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxContainerAdaptor.publishModuleEvent(EquinoxContainerAdaptor.java:168)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.publishEvent(Module.java:476)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.doStop(Module.java:634)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.stop(Module.java:498)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.SystemModule.stop(SystemModule.java:202)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle$SystemBundle$EquinoxSystemModule$1.run(EquinoxBundle.java:165)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:835)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.annotation.PreDestroy cannot be found by org.eclipse.e4.core.di_1.6.100.v20170421-1418
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:433)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:395)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:387)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:150)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    ... 21 more
```

I have 3 versions of Java Installed on my Mac

```
macbook:libexec aghan$ ./java_home -V
Matching Java Virtual Machines (3):
    12.0.2, x86_64: "Java SE 12.0.2"    /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-12.0.2.jdk/Contents/Home
    11.0.4, x86_64: "Java SE 11.0.4"    /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-11.0.4.jdk/Contents/Home
    1.8.0_221, x86_64:  "Java SE 8" /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_221.jdk/Contents/Home

/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-12.0.2.jdk/Contents/Home
```

I think I have to change the Default Version of the default Java of the Mac "Desktop" because in the terminal it is 1.8 already

```
macbook5434:libexec aghan$ java -version
java version "1.8.0_221"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_221-b11)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.221-b11, mixed mode)
```

**NOTE**: I edite the eclips.ini file like suggested in the comment below but it is still not working:

```
-startup 
../Eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.4.0.v20161219-1356.jar
--launcher.library
../Eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.cocoa.macosx.x86_64_1.1.500.v20170531-1133
-vm /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_221.jdk/Contents/Home/bin
-vm /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_221.jdk/Contents/Home/bin
-vmargs
-Xmx2G
-Xms200m
-XX:MaxPermSize=384m
-XstartOnFirstThread
-Dorg.eclipse.swt.internal.carbon.smallFonts
```

Comment: The missing classes were removed in Java 11, so you should run the Scala IDE with Java 8. As Scale-IDE is based on eclipse, you could try following this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24247384/setting-the-jdk-for-eclipse-in-mac to set the JVM version that the IDE will use.

Comment: @cello Thanks for the advice but still not working ...

Comment: '-vm' must be on a separate line from the /Library...  Alternatively use the current Eclipse (2019-09) which works with Java 12.